# Specify Action<T> callback as data with xml, possibly with cref attribute?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmlreader

I have an xml definitions file and one of the attributes that I want to specify for an object is a callback. It seems possible that I could specify the callback using the cref attribute, but I cannot figure out how to parse it as a method or Action. Something like this:

```
<XML>
    <ClassData>
        <Callback cref="CallbackClass.CallbackMethod"/>
    </ClassData>
</XML>
```

Then parsing it (in C#):

```
Action callbackActions;    

XmlReader reader; // I'm skipping w/e code gets the xml text into the reader

while(reader.Read()) {
    switch(reader.Name) {
        case "Callback":
        Action callback = ??? // How do I parse the cref attribute as an Action here?
        callbackActions += callback;
        break;   
    }
}
```

Or is there another way to accomplish the same goal?

I saw a somewhat related discussion somewhere that it might be possible to do with reflection, storing CallbackClass and CallbackMethod as strings. That seems like a very roundabout approach, though.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is technically possible, but inadvisable. You could use reflection to find a type named `CallbackClass` with a method named `CallbackMethod`. But it opens up cans of worms.

- Do you need to create an instance of CallbackClass? If so, does it have constructor parameters?
- Is CallbackMethod `static`?
- Does the method even exist?

When you're calling methods within your code, the compiler takes care of this for you. If you try to call a method that doesn't exist, it won't compile. If you try to call an instance method without creating an instance of a class, it won't compile.

If you store the names of methods and classes outside of your code - in XML or pretty much anything else - then you lose that safety net. You could refer to a method that doesn't exist or that you can't call for any number of reasons.

A better approach is to allow your application to determine what it should do based on what it finds in the XML document and then *let your application decide which methods it should call.*

For example:

```
while(reader.Read()) {
    switch(reader.Name) {
        case "Callback":
        callbackActions += SomeClass.SomeMethod;;
        break;   
    }
```